# DataOutputStream encoding and truncation

Tags: java

I am writing a socket programming application, and I'm wondering about `DataOutputStream`.

I have two questions:

1. What is the default encoding for bytes sent from `DataOutputStream`?
2. What is the max size of a `String` that `OutputStream.writeBytes(String s)` can send? Is it
   possible for the stream to truncate the String (and therefore be buggy)?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the first question - bytes don't have an encoding; they're just bytes. *Text* has an encoding applied to it when it's converted into bytes.

Comment: And `DataOutputStream.writeBytes(String)` doesn't truncate the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before talking about encoding in DataOutputStream, you need to say which method you are talking about:

1. [writeBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes(java.lang.String))
2. [writeChars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeChars(java.lang.String))
3. [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String))

In each case, the answer can be gleaned from looking at the javadoc:

1. Random, it only writes the lower eight bits of the char out.
2. Effectively `UTF-16HE`.
3. Using a `modified UTF-8` encoding.

To answer your second question, the only maximums on the string size that can be stored will be memory, otherwise you can't store the string, and free disk space.